# mostrar dato dinamico con php

Tags: php, html, mysql

```html
<!-- Nav Item - User Information -->
            <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="userDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="mr-2 d-none d-lg-inline text-gray-600 small"><?php echo $arr[1]." ".$arr[2] ?></span>
                <img class="img-profile rounded-circle" src="img/usuario.png">
              </a>
```

Cuando ingreso con un usuario quiero que me ponga su nombre en la parte del codigo que anexé, me podrian ayudar a corregirlo, por favor

Comment: ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar el resultado de hacer `var_export($arr);`?

Comment: Que tal, no puse en la descripcion que ese arreglo ya no lo uso, tendria que hacer algo nuevo para llamar al nombre de la persona que esta logueada